# How to stop/cancel a cucumber/ruby test when running from Sublime Text 3 (in Windows)?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am able to launch a Cucumber/Ruby test from Sublime 3 in Windows by right clicking and choosing Ruby Test-Run Single Test.

Things brings up the Test Panel with the results, but how can I cancel this execution and stop it from keep on running?

I've tried: ctrl+z, ctrl+x, ctrl+c, ctrl+pause_break, ctrl+delete, esc, delete, pause_break, but the test keep on running and you need to wait until it's all done...

I was pressing those keys either in the Test Panel, the console, or the main screen with code.

If you know what I could try pls?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that plugin, but if it's using a build system to run the tests, you might be able to stop it by selecting `Tools > Cancel Build` from the menu. This option is disabled unless a build is running, so if you can't select it, the plugin isn't using a build system.

Comment: It seems the plugin is launching the tests in a different way. That option is dosabled for me. But not sure which os the plugin provoding that option to run the test, I'll have to check later from the computer and see iif i can ask maybe in the community that has created it...